# how to call directly GSP in grails using RestFull api

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

i needs to call gsp page from restfull resources directly now am calling using groovy controller by using URI,but i need to call directly without using groovy controller ist possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could [directly map an url to a view](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#mappingToViews).

Just add a mapping to your `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/"(view: "/index")  // map the root URL to index view
        "/any/url"(view: "/anyview")
    }
}
```

Comment: No,i wanna call gsp in restfull api means from rest api resource i redirect to the particular view page

Comment: Instead of using "/" you could add any mapping for your gsp. Please add more information to your question so that it is clear what you want to archive.

Comment: See i have created restfull api now from rest full api i should redirect to view i.e gsp how to do? now am redirecting using controller means from rest api am returning to groovy controller an dfrom groovy controller am rendering gsp page, but actually am looking instead of creating groovy controller not possible to call gsp directly from rest api???

Comment: Please add some code - so it is much easier to help you.

Comment: Please edit your inital question and beside the code please add more information. For me - it is not clear what you what you want to do.